# How to force shut down a hibernated Virtual PC?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-xp-mode

How do i shut down a hibernated Virtual PC?

---

i have a virtual machine (Windows 7 XP Mode) that is hibernated:

[image]

i would like to shut this virtual machine down.

---

The help has a link that explains how to shut down a virtual PC:

[image]

It says:

> ### Shut down a virtual machine manually
>
> If a virtual machine is not configured to automatically shut down, you
>   can shut it down manually by following these steps.
>
> - **To shut down a virtual machine**
>
>   1. Do one of the following:
>
>      - To shut down from an open virtual machine, from the toolbar of the virtual machine window, click Ctrl+Alt+Del. Or, you can press the
>          CTRL+ALT+END key sequence.
>      - To shut down from a running virtual application, make sure the focus is on the application (click or restore it if necessary), and
>          then press the CTRL+ALT+END key sequence.
>   2. In the window that appears, click Shut down.
>   3. The operating system will go through the shutdown sequence, and the resources will be released from the virtual machine.
>
> To configure a virtual machine so that it automatically shuts down
>   when you close it, see Close a virtual machine.

These options don't help me, partly because i didn't ask how click a "*Shutdown*" button, but mainly because i cannot start the virtual machine to shut it down:

[image]

**Note**: We won't get into the quality of a user-interface where you have to boot a machine in order to shut it down.

How do i shut down a virtual machine?

How do i force shut down of a hibernated virtual machine?

Comment: I don't use Windows virtual pc anymore, but generally you'll have to find the file that holds the memory dump and delete it.

Comment: Older versions (at least up to 2007) *did* have an "Discard saved state" item in the context menu...

Comment: Kill the process from task manager. That will do the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do a clean shutdown if you can't start it.

To just in effect power off the virtual machine and lose any opened work not saved to disk: Look for and delete "Windows XP Mode.vsv" which should be in the same directory as the other virtual machine definition, data and disk image files. It should be listed as type "Virtual Machine Saved State" and be the same size as the RAM setting for the VM.